# How to use old Gmail audio player instead of Google Drive

Tags: gmail, audio

Gmail had included a simple audio player for a few years (since at least 2006); it used Flash and it was great. You didn't have to download the entire file to play it, no need for a dedicated player, etc.

[image: screenshot]

Now Google has replaced it with a Google Drive integration that won't work in my browser / OS, has no native player, requires more clicks, needs 3rd-party apps that won't work too, and requires lots of account access permissions:

[image: error message]

Is there a way to get the old player back?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm using Firefox 25 on Fedora 19 at work and Firefox 25 at Ubuntu 12.04 at home. What do you suggest?

Comment: Another option is to use [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) ($9.99) for Linux to sync your files with your computer, and then just use a native music player like Rhythmbox.

Comment: With a sync app, I'd have to download all my files from google drive, and all files in its entirety. Not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like for some reason Google doesn't like Firefox on Linux. I wasn't able to find any way to get Google's built in player to work, nor any indication from Google that they're even aware it has a problem.

---

Fortunately it's very easy to play files with a third party app.

1. Select one of your MP3 files by ticking the check box. Then, from the **More** menu, choose **Open with** then **Connect more apps**.

   [image: Open With on Google Drive]

   ---
2. Type `music player` in the search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Several search results will appear.

   [image: Search Google Drive apps for music player]

   ---
3. Choose a likely looking app and click **Connect**. For this example I chose **Music Player for Google Drive**.

   [image: Select a Google Drive App]

   ---
4. Allow the app to associate itself with its file types, and click **OK**.

   [image: App added to Google Drive]

   ---
5. Now click your MP3 file. A new window or tab should open with the third party music player.

   [image: Music Player for Google Drive]